# Query with Google sheet formula using Filter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a pretty straight forward issue, this is my Formula:

`=FILTER('Xero Report Paste Tab'!A7:N146,'Xero Report Paste Tab'!N7:N146 <0,'Xero Report Paste Tab'!N7:N146 > -30,REGEXMATCH('Xero Report Paste Tab'!A2:Z2,"Contact|Invoice Number|Total|Project Code"))`

My issue is the mismatched ranges causing Greif, how can i pull only the columns with the headers i want while it also having met the first 2 requirements if not with this formula?

Any explanation is always welcome as i'm learning!

Comment: Are you looking for any working formula? `QUERY` will work out if you do not need `FILTER`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Can you test:*

```js
=FILTER(
        FILTER('Xero Report Paste Tab'!A7:N146,REGEXMATCH('Xero Report Paste Tab'!A2:N2,"Contact|Invoice Number|Total|Project Code")),
 'Xero Report Paste Tab'!N7:N146 <0,'Xero Report Paste Tab'!N7:N146 > -30)
```

Comment: Wow, immediately worked, why does it not have the same range restriction when its the other way around?

Comment: 1, you are trying to apply both the horizontal filter(*A2:Z2*) & vertical filter(*N7:N146*) in one go which didnt work. 2, also header range column_size (*A2:Z2*) is *not equal to* the data range column_size(*A7:N146*)